# Restricted navigation React Router Dom - Private and Public routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I need to make a router system that distinguishes between authenticated and non-authenticated users.

What I want to achieve with this is that authed users can see their dashboard and personal details, but unauthed users can only see the landing page, the login form and the register form.

I currently have context management so I know whether a user is logged in or not. I just need to figure out all the redirects and routing related things.

My code is making all sorts of "strange" things. I don't really know where I have messed it up.

#### AppContent.js

This is where all the routing happens.
`AppLayout` is just a layout wrapper with a header and a footer that must be visible only when logged in.

```js
const AppContent = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute component={() => (<h1>Landing page</h1>)} path='/' exact />
            <PublicRoute component={LoginPage} path='/login' exact />
            <PublicRoute component={() => (<h1>Register page</h1>)} path='/register' exact />

            <PrivateRoute component={Home} path='/dashboard' exact />
            <PrivateRoute component={Demo} path='/demo' exact />
            <PrivateRoute component={Profile} path='/profile' exact />

            <PublicRoute component={() => (<h1>not found</h1>)} path='*' />
            <PrivateRoute component={() => (<h1>not found</h1>)} path='*' />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

#### PublicRoute.js

```js
const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const { user, isLoading } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (user ? <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> : <Component {...props} />)} />
    );
};
```

#### PrivateRoute.js

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const { user, isLoading } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => (user ? (
                <AppLayout>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </AppLayout>
            ) : <Redirect to='/login' />)}
        />
    );
};
```

#### AuthStore.js

This is where I manage my auth context.

```js
const AuthStore = ({ children }) => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState();
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const setUserToken = async (userToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', userToken);
        setToken(userToken);
        try {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(userToken);
            const currentUserData = await AuthService.getUserData(decodedToken.username);
            setUser(currentUserData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.name);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const localToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (localToken) {
            setUserToken(localToken);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            user, token, setUserToken, setUser, isLoading,
        }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Thank you so much.

## EDIT

What I am really looking for:
When Unauthorized:

- When searching for `/dashboard`, redirect to `/login` ✅
- When searching for non existing route, redirect to `/login` ✅
- When searching for another unauthorized route like `/register`, redirect to it fine ✅

When Authorized:

- When searching for `/login`, redirect to `/dashboard` ✅
- When searching for non existing route, redirect to a 404 page, preferably one of the two last routes, the ones that look like `<PrivateRoute component={() => (<h1>not found</h1>)} path='*'` ✅
- When searching for another authorized route like `/profile`, redirect to it fine ❌ ➡️ It is currently reloading the routes, showing the login page and after half a second it shows `/dashboard`, but not `/profile`

Comment: could you please describe what are the strange things that are happening? 
also i am not 100% sure, but i don't think switch will work with direct children that are not route or redirect, could you remove the layout component and see if it is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node) documentation, direct children of `<Switch>` component can only be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` components from react-router-dom package.

```
All children of a <Switch> should be <Route> or <Redirect> elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.
```

Your `<AppLayout />` component is the problem. Remove it from `<Switch>`and move it inside your auth pages.

**edit**

your auth provider is going trough async flow anytime you type in a new address in the browser and press enter, meaning every time you will have a state in your app where user is not logged in, then the components that are consuming this state are reacting to your change. also in the effect you should `await` setUserToken because loading is set to false before that async function resolves.

the last thing that is not working on your list is because you coded it like that ;), your public route redirects all calls it receives to the `/dashboard` if there is `user`, regardless if it should be a 404 route or existing route. i would suggest different approach. create a config where you declare if route is protected or not, then have only one AuthRoute component that will take all the props of the route, and based on this new flag and state of user in the context, do the work

```
const routes = [{ name: 'home', path: '/', exact: true, isProtected: false, component: Home }, { name: 'protected', path: '/dashboard', exact: true, isProtected: true, component: Dashboard }];

const AuthRoute = ({ name, path, exact, isProtected, component: Component }) => {
    const { user } = useContext(userContext);
    if (isProtected && !user) { // redirect to login }
    if (!isProtected || (isProtected && user)) { // render route with props }

}

///...

<Switch>
   {routes.map(route => <AuthRoute {...route} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I have done this and now it kinda works, this has fixed an error that consisted on redirecting to private routes if browsing for a non existing route when unauthorized, instead of redirecting to the 404 route. However, now when authorized if I search for /demo it will redirect me to /dashboard. This isn't happening when unauthorized, if I search for /register it redirects me well.

Comment: This is partially being caused by the last two routes, the 'not found' ones, if I change their order the app behaves in a different way.

Right now I want to achieve THIS:
- When Unauthorized: [When searching for /dashboard, redirect to /login], [When searching for non existing route, redirect to /login], [When searching for another unauthorized route, redirect to it fine] // - When Authorized: [When searching for /login, redirect to /dashboard], [When searching for non existing route, redirect to PrivateRoute path='*'], [When searching for another authorized route, redirect to it fine].

Comment: please edit your question with precise description what is happening and what is it that you want to happen

Comment: Done, I have added a list of requirements for my routing to be completely fine, and edited de JavaScript with the fixes you told me before about the <AppLayout />

Comment: When you say 'search for route' you mean you enter a path in addressbar and press enter? the app reloads?

Comment: Yes, if I enter a path in the addressbar the app reloads, but if I navigate using React Router's Link component it won't reload and in fact it works well. My issue is happening when searching for a path now.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the changes I should make to my code? Now I am not able to get to a protected route even if there is a logged user. And would you please complete the 'if' statements in your response? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problems just 3 to 4 days back when a very kind person who is just amazing, helped me out on the reactiflux server of discord.
You might be trying to go to one protected route and that would work but the other protected route will not work right??
All you have to do is create a Higher Order Component (HOC) in a separate file which you can maybe call `protectedRoute.js` and inside this file:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export function protectedRoute(Component) {
  return function ComponentCheck(props) {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      const user = false;
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setCheck(true);
    }, []);

    const RedirectToLogin = <Redirect to="/" />;

    return check && (currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : RedirectToLogin);
  };
}
```

In the above file the '/' route in my case is the login page but instead of `const RedirectToLogin = <Redirect to='/' />` you can say `const RedirectToLogin = <Redirect to='/login' />`

and then you can restrict a route like for example I want the `/users` route to be accessible only if `user === true`. So for that i can in the `users.js` file say:

```js
import { protectedRoute } from "./protectedRoute";

const Users = () => {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
};

export default protectedRoute(Users);
```

and then I also want the `/dashboard` route to be protected so:

```js
import { protectedRoute } from "./protectedRoute";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return <h2>Dashboard</h2>;
};

export default protectedRoute(Dashboard);
```

but I dont want the `/home` route to be protected so:

```js
const Home = () => {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
};

export default Home;
```